# Logic in MySQL Query To Skip Days

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a website where people can go fix appointment to doctor.On the day before the doctors appointment the help desk calls the patient to make sure their presence on the day of appointment.

Now I made a Screen in Admin which Shows people who ever have appointment tomorrow.In case tomorrow is Sunday on Saturday it should show those who have fixed appointment on monday since clinic will be closed on Sunday.

I made a query which brings people list who have appointment tomorrow.Now what should i Add to this query in order to get people list for monday incase  tomorrow is sunday.

```
CREATE TABLE Patients_Appointment_List(
  Patent_Id INT  UNSIGNED PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Patient_Name VARCHAR(255),
  appointment_Date DATE  
);
```

What Should I add To Below Query To Skip Sunday and Start Again From Monday

```
SELECT Patient_Name
  FROM Patients_Appointment_List
 WHERE appointment_Date BETWEEN now() and date_add(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause to check if tomorrow is Sunday. If it is, adjust the conditional check to include the next **two** days, otherwise, just show appointments up until tomorrow:

```
SELECT Patient_Name
FROM   Patients_Appointment_List
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) = 6 THEN 
         appointment_Date BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY ELSE
         appointment_Date BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    END
```

Comment: I included a case when the start date occurs on Sunday.

Comment: @RosePerrone Well if the clinic is closed on Sunday, then there shouldn't be any appointments scheduled for Sunday should there?...